# Java Swing application JList null exception

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a java swing application which is to be used for searching some data(extracted from Hierarchical database through JDBC). For testing purpose, I have made it like this:-

Level-1 : 1, 2, 3
Level-2 : {1.1, 1.2, 1.3}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}, {3.1, 3.2, 3.3}
Level-3 : {1.1.1, 1.1.2},{1.2.1, 1.2.2}, ..., {3.3.1, 3.3.2}

UI is like this:-
Level-1 will be displayed in JComboBox.
Level-2 is also a JComboBox but gets populated via ComboBoxModel depends on  level-1 selectedIndex.
Level-3 I want to display in a JList dependent of level-1 & level-2 as in level-3.

level-1 & level-2 is working fine. But level-3 is giving 'NullPointerException' when I try to initiate level3values attributes.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestSwing extends JPanel implements Runnable, ActionListener {

    private JComboBox combo1;
    private JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox();
    private ComboBoxModel[] models ;
    private JList<String> list;
    private DefaultListModel<String>[][] level3values;
    //TODO:add displaying level3, copy method
    public TestSwing(String[] level1candidates, String[][] level2candidates, String[][][] level3candidates){

        this.models = new ComboBoxModel[level1candidates.length];
        this.combo1 = new JComboBox(level1candidates);
        for (int i=0; i<level1candidates.length; i++ )
            models[i] = new DefaultComboBoxModel(level2candidates[i]);
        for (int i=0; i<level1candidates.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<level2candidates[i].length; j++) {
                level3values[i][j] = new DefaultListModel<String>();
                for (int k=0; k<level3candidates[i][j].length; k++) {
                    this.level3values[i][j].addElement(level3candidates[i][j][k]);
                } ;//TODO:DEBUG-how to initiate list model
            }
        }
        combo2.setModel(models[0]);
        this.list = new JList<String>(new String[]{});
        this.add(combo1);
        this.add(combo2);
        this.add(list);
        this.combo1.addActionListener(this);
        this.combo2.addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int i = combo1.getSelectedIndex();
        combo2.setModel(models[i]);
        int j = combo2.getSelectedIndex();
        list.setModel(level3values[i][j]);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("CPBG-Store_Material-Finder");
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel controlPane = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(3,2, 10, 10);
        controlPane.setLayout(gridLayout);
        controlPane.add(new JLabel("Level-1"));
        controlPane.add(this.combo1);
        controlPane.add(new JLabel("Level-2"));
        controlPane.add(this.combo2);
        controlPane.add(new JLabel("Level-3"));
        //controlPane.add(new JLabel("Level-4"));
        controlPane.add(this.list);
        f.add(controlPane);
        //f.pack();
        //f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] level1candidates = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
        String[][] level2candidates = {new String[]{"1.1", "1.2", "1.3"},
                new String[]{"2.1", "2.2", "2.3"}, new String[]{"3.1", "3.2", "3.3"}};
        String[][][] level3candidates = {
                {new String[]{"1.1.1", "1.1.2"},new String[]{"1.2.1", "1.2.2"}, new String[]{"1.3.1","1.3.2"}},
                {new String[]{"2.1.1", "2.1.2"},new String[]{"2.2.1", "2.2.2"}, new String[]{"2.3.1","2.3.2"}},
                {new String[]{"3.1.1", "3.1.2"},new String[]{"3.2.1", "3.2.2"}, new String[]{"3.3.1","3.3.2"}},
                };
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TestSwing(level1candidates, level2candidates, level3candidates));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help for debugging the problem.

In particular comboboxmodel[] is working fine but defaultlistmodel[][] is giving null pointer exception, is there any particular reason?

Here is the working code for two levels:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MaterialFinder extends JPanel implements Runnable, ActionListener {

    private JComboBox combo1;
    private JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox();
    private ComboBoxModel[] models ;

    public MaterialFinder(String[] level1candidates, String[][] level2candidates, String[][][] level3candidates){

        this.models = new ComboBoxModel[level1candidates.length];
        this.combo1 = new JComboBox(level1candidates);
        for (int i=0; i<level1candidates.length; i++ )
            models[i] = new DefaultComboBoxModel(level2candidates[i]);
        combo2.setModel(models[0]);
        this.add(combo1);
        this.add(combo2);
        this.combo1.addActionListener(this);
        this.combo2.addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int i = combo1.getSelectedIndex();
        combo2.setModel(models[i]);
        int j = combo2.getSelectedIndex();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("CPBG-Store_Material-Finder");
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.add(this);
        //f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JDBCUtilities jdbcUtilities = new JDBCUtilities();
        jdbcUtilities.dbName = "cpbg";
        jdbcUtilities.userName = "root";
        jdbcUtilities.password = "root";
        jdbcUtilities.serverName = "localhost";
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            connection = jdbcUtilities.getConnection();
            //TODO:copy SQL code here
        } catch (SQLException se) {

            jdbcUtilities.printSQLException(se);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } finally {

            jdbcUtilities.closeConnection(connection);
        }
        //TODO:remove the following dummyLevelCandidate
        String[] level1candidates = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
        String[][] level2candidates = {new String[]{"1.1", "1.2", "1.3"},
                new String[]{"2.1", "2.2", "2.3"}, new String[]{"3.1", "3.2", "3.3"}};
        String[][][] level3candidates = {
                {new String[]{"1.1.1", "1.1.2"},new String[]{"1.2.1", "1.2.2"}, new String[]{"1.3.1","1.3.2"}},
                {new String[]{"2.1.1", "2.1.2"},new String[]{"2.2.1", "2.2.2"}, new String[]{"2.3.1","2.3.2"}},
                {new String[]{"3.1.1", "3.1.2"},new String[]{"3.2.1", "3.2.2"}, new String[]{"3.3.1","3.3.2"}},
                };
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MaterialFinder(level1candidates, level2candidates, level3candidates));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
level3values[i][j] = new DefaultListModel<String>();
```

since `level3values` is `null`. So you should properly initialize it with the proper dimensions as your data would be. So before the nested for loops for initializing the models you should initialize it:

```
this.level3values = new DefaultListModel[level2candidates.length][level2candidates.length];
```

** `level2candidates.length` is just a sample that shows how the problem would be solved.